# Access excel cell by its name

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm trying to set excel's cell name to some custom name and to later access that cell by its name.
Is there some out of the box API call to do this, or how should I do this if I have information of worksheet and cell name in case of accessing cell and 
worksheet and cell address (i.e. C2) in case of naming the cell.

Also to ask, is there a way to acquire formatting information that is bound to that specific cell?
(i.e. When I'm accessing cell by name I want to return cell value and some formatting properties of this cell, if cell is number or text, is it highlighted, etc...)

regards,

Vladimir Vajda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `Range("C2")`.

As to formatting information, this is available through various properties of the Excel object model.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff197454.aspx for more information.

The `Range` type (as opposed to the `Range` indexed property referenced above) also exposes a `Name` property, which you can set in code:

```
worksheet.get_Range("C2").Name = "fdafdfs"
worksheet.get_Range("fdafdfs").Select();
```

Comment: Is this Range("C2") is working when I change C2 cell name to "fdafdfs"?

Comment: How do you change the name of the cell?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find out how to do that programmatically. But manualy you can just change cell name when select cell and at the bar place where is written C2 enter another string.

Comment: @phoog See more info on [defined names](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefinedNames.aspx)

Comment: Thanks phoog, that is straight forward solution.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer looks a bit outdated (there is no `get_Range` on the `Worksheet` object available), here how it works now:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// ...
// Excel.Worksheet workSheet = ...

Excel.Range cell = workSheet.Range["P3"];
// or
Excel.Range cell = workSheet.Cells[3, "P"];

cell.Name = "lorem";

// access via name
Excel.Range loremCell = workSheet.Range["lorem"];
```