# Query excel cell by name

Tags: c#, excel

Is there any way to select an Excel cell from it's column name(A,B,C), or row number, in C#? 
This cell name defined by right click on cell -> select "Name a Range" -> Add to name.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not so unclear if you read the original post before the first edit was made (it was approved but it changed the meaning of the question). Basically, he's got a cell in his workbook that has a "name", i.e. it's a named range, and he wants to access that cell from C# with the name and not the column/row index. Hopefully my explanation will allow someone who knows about this stuff to help him, because I can't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072185/access-excel-cell-by-its-name